# Quitar corchetes de un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy iniciando en esto de Java y tengo un problema. Hago una consulta en mysql y guardo los datos en un ArrayList, del cual solo necesito los datos, sin los corchetes que aparecen al inicio y final. 
¿Alguien me podría ayudar diciendome como quitar esos corchetes?

```
    public class ArregloObservadas {

public ArrayList setArregloOBS_1(){

    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        ResultSetMetaData RSMD;
        Connection conn=null;

        ArrayList tmp3 = null;

        String sql2;

        conexion opendb = new conexion();

        try{    conn = opendb.getConnection();
        } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

        try{
            sql2 = "**consulta**";

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

            rs   = pstmt.executeQuery();
            RSMD = rs.getMetaData();

            tmp3 = new ArrayList();  

            while (rs.next()){
                tmp3.add(rs.getInt("id_comision"));

            }

            if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
                rs=null;
            }
            if(pstmt!=null){
                pstmt.close();
                pstmt = null;
            }
            if(conn!=null){
                conn.close();
                conn=null;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }finally{
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
                rs=null;
                }
                if(pstmt!=null){
                    pstmt.close();
                    pstmt = null;
                }
                if(conn!=null){
                    conn.close();
                    conn=null;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        return tmp3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArregloObservadas x = new ArregloObservadas();
        System.out.println(x.setArregloOBS_1());
    }
```

Comment: vos estas seguro que aparecen los corchetes?? o en el debug ves los corchetes?? que es una forma de mostrar que son items distintos en la lista.. dudo que se agreguen corchetes de mas.. tal vez deberias revisar mejor la documentacion de los objetos que usas.. y de paso mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Y el código? Edita tu pregunta, agrega el código que estás utilizando para ayudarte una manera más acertada :D

Comment: Estoy seguro que aparecen los corchetes en la salida. Ya incluí el código.

Comment: .replace("[","").replace("]","");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los corchetes que comentas se muestran porque estas imprimiendo la representación del `ArrayList`, por ejemplo algo similar a esto:

```
[Valor1, Valor2, Valor3, Valor4, Valor5]
```

Sin embargo esto no debe significar un problema en cuanto al manejo  de los datos contenidos en el `ArrayList`, pero si tu objetivo es imprimir los valores, puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
    String datosArray = "";
    for (String elemento: myArrayList) {
        datosArray += elemento + ", ";
    }
    System.out.println(datosArray);
```

agrega este método para limpiar el último `,`  :

```
private static String limpia(String datosArray){
     datosArray = datosArray.trim();
     if (datosArray != null && datosArray.length() > 0 && datosArray.charAt(datosArray.length() - 1) == ',') {           
       datosArray = datosArray.substring(0, datosArray.length() - 1);              
     }
     return datosArray;
}
```

y llamalo de esta forma:

```
  System.out.println(limpia(datosArray));
```

de esta forma obtendrías:

```
Valor1, Valor2, Valor3, Valor4, Valor5
```

---

En el caso de tu código sería  :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArregloObservadas x = new ArregloObservadas();
        //System.out.println(x.setArregloOBS_1());

        String datosArray = "";
        for (String elemento : x.setArregloOBS_1()) {
            datosArray += elemento + ", ";
        }
        System.out.println(limpia(datosArray));

    }
```

Comment: Me funciona, pero solo me manda los valores sin que estos esten separados por comas. Y en el for, mi IDE me fuerza a cambiar de `String elemento` a `Object elemento`

Comment: @Lía0512 El separador debe ser:  + ", "

Comment: Lo mismo pensé, pero ahora me pone el mismo separador en el ultimo dato y con eso ya no me funciona para mi siguiente consulta :(

Comment: hehe, revisa la respuesta, agrega el método limpia() y llama   System.out.println(limpia(datosArray));

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me has ayudado bastante, ya me funciona correctamente :) @Jorgesys

Answer (score 3):

A partir de Java 8 puedes usar el Método join de la clase String de esta manera:

```
String listString = String.join(", ", list);
```

En el caso de que uses una versión de java anterior a 8, la otra respuesta es la adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega esta simple linea y problema resuelto :

```
arreglo_molesto.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", ""));
```

Eso si, a la hora de llenarlo hazlo de esta forma:

```
arreglo_molesto.add(algo + "\n");
```

para que el separador sea un salto de linea.